# strange error when trying to install laravel homestead

Tags: php, macos, laravel, terminal, vagrant

I am following an online training course which is showing me how to install laravel, I am having trouble installing homestead, I followed the instruction to download Vagrant and Virtualbox which I have done. Then I am told to run a terminal command:

```
   $ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I get the following strange message:

```
    /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78:in `set_bundle_environment'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222:in `setup_environment'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:15:in `setup'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler.rb:129:in `setup'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:71:in `<main>'
```

and then nothing happens.

Could anybody please tell me what is going on. especially with the - 'split' : invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError).

I am on Yosemite 10.10.4.

Comment: Do you have non-ASCII characters in your paths?

Comment: do you mean in my bash_profile file...? Is so,then not that I can see.

Comment: I mean in the path where you installed Vagrant. Looking at your debug output, I don't think that's the problem however. Try running this command first: `$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: I ran this command but got no message at all, then I retried the homestead command and still the same error....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing path to .vagrant.d

```
export VAGRANT_HOME="..."
```